# Free java 3d engine

Tags: java, 3d

Whats the best 3D game engine available for java? I am looking for something that has a good set visual development tools.  I have checked out the list available on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

But I can't figure out the tool set provided by each engine and which free java 3d engine has the best toolset.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 2D Game Frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293079/java-2d-game-frameworks)

Answer (score 15):

[jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) has a nice set of open source tools for 3d java development.  They have been used for a few commercial games ([Bang!Howdy](http://www.banghowdy.com/) and one that NCSoft was developing that was recently cancelled come to mind off hand).  They have a good set of active developers with many code samples provided with the basic toolset.

Answer (score 5):

**[Ardor3D](http://www.ardor3d.com/)**

A fork of the JMonkeyEngine including two previous developers from JMonkeyEngine team. Essentially a more broad 3d engine with a clear(-er) API.

Comment: Ardor3D is no longer maintained (since March 2014) but I still work on JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Ardor3D_Overview

Answer (score 1):

[OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) is a good open source engine for C++. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OGRE_Engine).

[Ogre4j](http://ogre4j.sourceforge.net/) is same thing for Java. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogre4j).

Answer (score 1):

a powerfull Java 3D engine is [3DzzD](http://dzzd.net/)

including both software and hardware rendering, it is perfect for Web 3D

Comment: 3DzzD has been discontinued a while ago according to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

The [Lightweight Java Game Library](http://lwjgl.org/)  is a pretty good one.

Comment: This is more of a wrapper than a 3D engine

Comment: yxk is right, it's a set of low level bindings, it's not an engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning Java at the same time, and would like to write simple 3D games, try Env3D (http://env3d.sourceforge.net).

Comment: It's a quite very poor engine.