# Rendering Java based 3D output on a Nvidia 3D display

Tags: java

I wanted to code a java based 3D application which can be displayed on Nvidia 3D displays.I am aware that I would require the Nvidia 3D setup namely:
1. 120hz 3D monitor.
2. Shutter glassed 
3. IR emitter etc
4. NVidia Quadro

But I wanted to know if Java3D is the languge of choice or would I be better using some game engines mentioned here:
[Free java 3d engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269916/free-java-3d-engine)

I am primarily looking for ease of development and avoid any compatibility issue/bugs which
may be encountered when using a particular language with nvidia 3D solutions.

If something like this has already done by someone, I would be very grateful if he could share his experience and tell me how did he/she coded the application(using which engine)

Also if there are any additional drivers/software required for such a process please do mention that as well.

Finally, I came across a Nvidia forum which said 3D can only be displayed on Nvidia screens in Full screen mode.
http://www.java.net/node/705596

What would be an appropriate solution for this?

I am new to graphics/game programming and am doing it for my masters project.
Please forgive me if my questions are lame:

Regards
RS