# OpenGL ES model loader example

Tags: java, c++, opengl-es, shader

I want to load a model in any format with lighting and bump mapping using OpenGL with shaders. Where can I find examples on c++ or java?

Comment: this is a very general question and sort of duplicates both this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365316/3d-engine-comparison and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269916/free-java-3d-engine

Comment: This is a big complicated engines, but I want simple example.

Comment: what you are asking for an example of is not simple, any example would be very large and complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your question has a simple answer. There is neither any single, nor any "mostly used" standard model file format for 3D engines. While there are a couple of standards, most of them are old and don't support many features, so many engines use their own file formats that fit their own requirements.

The standards that do exist, such as Ogre XML, are not even particularly commonly used, and when they are used, it's mostly for "behind the scenes"-work when creating the models, and are then often "compiled" to some engine-specific format for actual inclusion in a game or program.

You can study some open-source libraries, such as [JME](http://jmonkeyengine.com/), [the Jogamp samples](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) or [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/) and see how they load models, but I haven't seen any "simple" examples. The Jogamp samples are probably the most simple, but they are also somewhat overly simple; they certainly don't include any bumpmapping or such.

If you want lots of features without having to implement it all yourself from scratch, then you're probably better off using some premade game-engine library such as JME or Ogre, rather than using OpenGL directly.